# How do I query the content of the addStringOption in the interactions in discord v13?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Good day,

I would like to save the content that you type in addStringOption, I just don't know how to query that, can someone explain it to me?

```
   const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
    
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('announce')
        .setDescription('test')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>subcommand.setName('normal').setDescription('TEST')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('message').setDescription('TEST').setRequired(true))),
    
        async execute(interaction) {
            interaction.reply("test")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% what you mean by query but I assume you want to get the value of the option they user has entered. For this you want to use the getString function on the options property.

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  // Get the string option
  const value = interaction.options.getString('message');
  // Return the value
  await interaction.reply(value);
}
```

Read More Here:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getString